# Keyboard shortcut stopped working in Safari 6.0

Tags: safari, keyboard, macos

I've created a custom keyboard shortcut for entering and exiting fullscreen in the keyboard preferences menu.

This stopped working for Safari 6.0 after I upgraded to Mountain Lion. I had the beta version of Safari which I got from the developers' site before I upgraded and the keyboard shortcut worked on that one.

So, how do I get this keyboard shortcut to work with Safari again? (Hopefully there's a simple explanation instead of some Automator workaround)

Comment: Have you tried removing the shortcut from Keyboard Preferences and then re-adding it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to System Preferences.
2. Click on “Keyboard.” Navigate to Keyboard Shortcuts.
3. Select Application Shortcuts in the left pane and remove existing shortcuts for Safari, if any.
4. Add a shortcut by clicking the “+” button. In the Menu Title field, type “Enter Full Screen.” Remember, you have to type the exact title as it appears in Safari.
5. Add another shortcut and in the menu title field and type “Exit Full Screen” in the Menu Title field.
6. Make sure there are no conflicts with the shortcut combination that you choose to use.

Hope this helps.

PS: Be careful of the space between “Full” and “Screen” in the menu title.

Comment: That's the setup I had. I was not aware of a conflict (since there really doesn't seem to be one) but changing from "ctrl + f" to " ctrl + cmd + f" fixes it. So, does "ctrl + f" do something undetectable on safari 6? (googling got me nothing)

Comment: Using ctrl for keyboard shortcuts doesn’t work very well. There are usually escape characters assigned to these shortcuts. It’s very rare for an OS X shortcut to have only ctrl as a modifier key.